# LuaLaTeX is not rendering 'ť' character with Andika New Basic font

Tags: fonts, luatex

LuaLaTeX does not render the 'ť' on the second and last line in 'ať'. XeLaTeX does that correctly.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=A6]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[]{Andika New Basic}
\title{Říkanky}
\date{}

\begin{document}

Čistím zoubky řízy, řízy,\\
ať jsou bílé jako břízy.\\
Vlevo, vpravo, vpředu, vzadu,\\
horní a pak dolní řadu,\\
čistím zoubky řízy, říz,\\
ať má každý radost z nich.

\end{document}
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/2EfIzNe.png]

vs

[image]

**UPDATE**

Now that I look closer at log file, I can see

```
Missing character: There is no ť in font Andika New Basic/OT:script=latn;langua
ge=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;mapping=tex-text;!
```

Comment: Would it help to make ť an active character (change its catcode) then define it as a macro that places the diacritical mark on ordinary t ?

Comment: There's something weird here, even in the XeLaTeX output: the character in your input is `ť` which is U+0165 LATIN SMALL LETTER T WITH CARON. The glyphs I can find for this character, in most fonts (in basically every font on my system, which doesn't include Andika New Basic), look like t with an apostrophe or a single accent; they don't look like the hacek in Č ř č or ž. Is this acceptable font-variation that's present in Andika New Basic, or is something else happening?

Comment: If I open `AndikaNewBasic-R.ttf` with fontforge, I see no glyph at U+0357 (LATIN SMALL LETTER T WITH CARON)

Comment: Strictly, both are incorrect. See for example https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A4 or https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A4 .

Comment: @JavierBezos No, they are not both correct. You place the standard form over the capitals, and the "apostrophe-like" form over the miniscules. So both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX got it wrong, but probably it's the font to blame.

Comment: @yo' This is exacly what I said. The solution below is wrong, too.

Comment: @JavierBezos Damn, I missed "in" in "incorrect" :( sorry for that.

Comment: @yo' Don't worry :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
\documentclass[paper=A6]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
%\setmainfont[]{Andika New Basic}
\setmainfont[]{AndikaNewBasic-R.ttf}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{ť}{t^^^^030c}

\title{Říkanky}
\date{}

\begin{document}

Čistím zoubky řízy, řízy,\\
ať jsou bílé jako břízy.\\
Vlevo, vpravo, vpředu, vzadu,\\
horní a pak dolní řadu,\\
čistím zoubky řízy, říz,\\
ať má každý radost z nich.

\end{document}
```

xetex (or rather harfbuzz) will attempt to fill in composites that are missing in the font by using the base and a combining accent. Here I use `\newunicodechar` to do the same at the macro level, declaring ť as an active character to expand to `\v{t}` so it works in luatex and xetex.

[image]

---

---

**2017 update**

In the 2017/01/01 releases of latex and fontspec due soon, a simpler declaration form will be possible, you can declare a new unicode variant encoding that does not have the pre-composed ť so declare `\v{t}` to use instead the default `\v` accent which will use `t` followed by a combining v accent, so produce identical output to the above but without needing to use `^^^^030c` explicitly and without affecting `t` in other fonts used in the document that may still use a precomposed glyph.

```
\documentclass[paper=A6]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\DeclareUnicodeEncoding{TUX}{%
\input{tuenc.def}% load usual definitions
\UndeclareComposite{\v}{t}% This variant has no ť
}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ť}{\v{t}}% make ť act like \v{t}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
%\setmainfont[]{Andika New Basic}
\setmainfont[NFSSEncoding=TUX]{AndikaNewBasic-R.ttf}


\title{Říkanky}
\date{}

\begin{document}

Čistím zoubky řízy, řízy,\\
ať jsou bílé jako břízy.\\
Vlevo, vpravo, vpředu, vzadu,\\
horní a pak dolní řadu,\\
čistím zoubky řízy, říz,\\
ať má každý radost z nich.


\end{document}
```

Comment: On LuaTeX 0.95 this doesn't work: nothing shows. It does if I do `\newunicodechar{ť}{t^^^^030c}`

Comment: @egreg it doesn't? what does it do?  do you mean that `\v{t}` already fails or that the active ť does not work? I'm using luatex 1.0.2

Comment: @egreg turns out that the fact that my original version worked was due to an undocumented feature in the development sources of the next latex release, now removed so I've edited the example just to use the combining character form.